# Calculating the balance fulcrum point

Tags: calculus

I have a piece of wood with buckets that are filled with water on it. The length of the plank is known as well as how far way each bucket is located form the one edge. How do I calculate the balance fulcrum point ?

[image: Balance]

Comment: Please show what you have done to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straight forward.   Let the distance from the left side (0) to the fulcrum be x.  The clockwise and counterclockwise torques (force times distance from the fulcrum) have to be equal.

(I wish you had chosen a better color scheme.  It is hard to read yellow on green!  I think this is 1 kg, 2kg, 3 kg, 2kg, left to right.)

The left most mass, 1 kg, is distance 0- x= -x from the fulcrum.  Force times distance is 1k times -x (strictly speaking times "g", the acceleration due to gravity but we that will occur in every term and cancel so we can ignore it).  The next mass to the right, 2kg, is .2 m from the left so .2- x from the fulcrum and contributes 2(.2- x)= .4- 2x torque.  The third mass, 3 kg, is 0.65 m from the left so .65- x from the fulcrum and contributes 3(.65-x)= 1.95- 3x torque.  The last mass, 2 kg, is 1 m from the left so 1- x from the fulcrum and contributes 2(1- x)= 2- 2x torque.

The total torque is -x+ .4- 2x+ 1.95- 3x+ 2- 2x= 4.35- 8x.  That must be 0 to be in equilibrium. Solve 4.35- 8x= 0 for x.

Comment: Sorry about the yellow and green.....

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one way to do it.
[Posible answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uqOd.png)